# Holomorphic function defined on open unit disc that is not in any Hardy space

Tags: complex-analysis

The following question is heavily inspired by Greene and Krantz, Problem 2, page 412:

> Find a holomorphic function $f$ that is defined on the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ but is not in $H^p$ for $0<p< \infty$.

Since the function $\frac{1}{(1-z)^q}$ is not in $H^1$ for $q>1$, I'm pretty sure that a holomorphic function with no essential singularity on the boundary $\partial \mathbb{D}$ will not give us the $f$ we want. I think $e^\frac{1}{1-z}$ is an example that works, but can't prove it. I also suspect that any holomorphic function defined on $\mathbb{D}$ with an essential singularity on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ will give us the $f$ that we want but, again, don't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi$ be a Mobius transform that maps $\partial \mathbb D$ to $\mathbb R$.  Then consider $z \mapsto \exp(\phi(z))$.

Also, $z\mapsto \exp(i\phi(z))$ will have an essential singularity, but will be in $H^\infty$.